# Could you explain this code to me clearly for java?

Tags: java, recursion, permutation

While trying to do a problem on permutation with recursion, I saw this solution on the Internet, but I'm not sure how this produces every possible permutations of an array.

A clear, concise explanation would be greatly appreciated

```
public static void permute(int [] list, int index){
    if(index == list.length){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(list));
    }
    else{
        for(int i = index; i < list.length; i++){
            swap(list, index, i);
            knapsack(list, index + 1);
            swap(list, index, i);
        }
    }
}
public static void swap (int [] a, int b, int c){
    int temp = a[b];
    a[b] = a[c];
    a[c] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you posted the code exactly as you found it? It's not recursive.

Comment: where is your knapsack method defined?

Comment: I presume it's supposed to be `permute` instead of `knapsack`?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that `knapsack` is supposed to be `permute` in your example code.  Also, there's an important piece missing: there has to be code that gets the whole process started, something like

```
public static void printAllPermutations(int[] list) {
    permute(list, 0);
}
```

The essence of recursion is that you solve a problem by solving smaller instance(s) of the same problem, and those smaller solutions solve even smaller instances, and so on, until you get to a "base case".  Suppose `printAllPermutations` is called with this list:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

This calls `permute(list,0)`.  The logic in the loop uses `swap` to get each element into the first element, and then swaps them back; the result is that it will be working with each of these lists:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 1, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 2, 1, 4, 5]
[4, 2, 3, 1, 5]
[5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

The recursive call causes the code to find all permutations of the last four elements.  Thus, when you work with `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`, the `permute` method computes all permutations of `[2, 3, 4, 5]` (the smaller instance of the same problem).  That means that for each permutation of `[2, 3, 4, 5]`, the method will output that permutation, with a 1 in front.  And similarly for all permutations of `[1, 3, 4, 5]`, it will output each permutation with a 2 in front, and so on.  If you can trust that the method works right for those four elements, then you can see that it will work for five elements.  And if you can trust that it works for three elements, then you can trust that it will work for four elements, and so on.  And when it gets down to zero elements, there's nothing to do, because there's only one permutation.  (Actually, when it gets down to one element, there's nothing to do, which means the first `if` could have been `if (index >= list.length-1)`.)  That's the "base case".  Since there's only one permutation, and it doesn't involve changing the list at all, the only thing left to do is print it.